# Sending additional parameters to editurl on JQgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datagrid, jqgrid

My problem now is trying to send the ID (`editable: false`) of a row when editing that row.

For example, i have a grid with columns userid(`editable: false`), username(`editable: true`), firstname(`editable: true`), lastname(`editable: true`). When editing the row the grid is only sending the parameters username, firstname and lastname. In the server side i need the userid to know to which user i've tu apply those new values.

the editUrl looks like:

```
editurl : CONTEXT_PATH+'/ajax/admin/savePart.do?category=1',
```

Thanks

This is the full code:

```
$.jgrid.useJSON = true;
//http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Acommon_rules
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert(CONTEXT_PATH);
    var lastsel;
    jQuery("#rowed3").jqGrid(
            {
                url : CONTEXT_PATH+'/ajax/getPartesByCategory.do?catid=<s:property value="categoryId" />',
                //url : '/autoWEB/text.html',
                datatype: "json",
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                jsonReader : { 
                    root: "rows", 
                    page: "page", 
                    total: "total", 
                    records: "records", 
                    repeatitems: false 
                },
                headertitles: true,
                colNames : [ 'ID', 'Pieza', 'Disponible'],
                colModel : [ {
                    name : 'piezaId',
                    index : 'piezaId',
                    align : "right",
                    width : 50, 
                    editable : false,
                    required : true
                }, {
                    name : 'descripcion',
                    index : 'descripcion',
                    width : 390,
                    editable : true,
                    required : true
                }, {
                    name : 'disponible',
                    index : 'disponible',
                    width : 80,
                    editable : true,
                    edittype : 'select',
                    editoptions:{value:"0:No;1:Si"},
                    required : true
                } ],
                rowNum : 20,
                rowList : [ 20, 40, 60, 80 ],
                pager : '#prowed3',
                sortname : 'piezaId',
                postData: {piezaId : lastsel},
                mtype:"POST",
                viewrecords : true,
                sortorder : "desc",
                onSelectRow : function(id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                        jQuery('#rowed3').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        jQuery('#rowed3').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                        lastsel = id;
                    }
                },
                editurl : CONTEXT_PATH+'/ajax/admin/savePieza.do?categoria=<s:property value="categoryId" />',
                caption : "Piezas"
            });
    jQuery("#rowed3").jqGrid('navGrid', "#prowed3", {
        edit : false,
        add : false,
        del : false
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true
```

in the definition of the `piezaId` (ID) column. The parameter `hidedlg` is currently not real needed, but can be useful if you decide the use other jqGrid features.

Comment: If `hidedlg` set to true this column will not appear in the modal dialog where users can choose which columns to show or hide (`columnChooser`). See http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:show_hide_columns for more details.

Answer (score 3):

in your onSelectRow callback, you can modify the editUrl to be whatever you want, including passing in the ID you need.

```
$("#rowed3").jqGrid('setGridParam', {editurl:'whatever/url/you/need/with/the/id'});
```

jqGrid will add all the other nececessary params to that editurl for you.

Answer (score 0):

Passing values in the GET string worked for me.

```
editurl: '/ajax/update?line=1',
```