# Hide column in jqGrid display but show it in edit/add screen?

Tags: jqgrid

In my jqGrid I want to pass in 5 rows from my model and display 3 of them in the grid but have all 5 show up in the edit and add popup window that jqGrid generates. I know I can add the `hidden: true` attribute in the `colModel` settings to prevent it from showing up but this also hides it from the popup window. Is there some way of hiding columns from the grid but show it when adding or editing data?

My Grid code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function ()
    {
        $( '#Sections' ).jqGrid( {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['ID', 'RouteName', 'Title', 'File', 'Description'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 10, sorttype: 'int' },
                        { name: 'RouteName', index: 'RouteName', width: 50, editable: true, edittype: 'text'},
                        { name: 'Title', index: 'Title' },
                        { name: 'File', index: 'File', hidden: true },
                        { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', hidden: true }
            ],
            autowidth: true,
            height: '100%',
            pager: $( '#SectionsPager' ),
            sortname: 'ID',
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            multiSort: true,
        } );
        $( '#Sections' ).jqGrid( 'navGrid', '#SectionsPager',
            //enabling buttons
            { add: true, del: false, edit: true, search: true },
           //add options
           { width: 'auto' },
           //edit options
           { width: 'auto' },
           //delete options
           {}
        );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via Oleg's answer at

[Sending additional parameters to editurl on JQgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176157/sending-additional-parameters-to-editurl-on-jqgrid/3177531#3177531)

```
hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true}, hidedlg: true
```

The `editrules: { edithidden: true}` section will "turn on" your column when editing.

Comment: You where close `eddithidden` needs to be set to `true` not false, if you update your answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

u can use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) in your add/edit and make it hidden or not

```
beforeShowForm:  function(form) { 
$("#tr_columnname").hide(); 
    $("#tr_columnname").show();
}
```